# C++ coroutine causes stack overflow

Tags: c++, stack-overflow, c++-coroutine

In Visual Studio 2022 (C++20 build) I get a stack overflow exception with the following code (operator new never gets called) :

```
struct cCoro
{
    struct promise_type
    {
        cCoro get_return_object() {
            return {
                // Uses C++20 designated initializer syntax
                .Handle = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this)
            };
        }

        std::suspend_always initial_suspend() { return {}; }
        std::suspend_always final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
        void unhandled_exception() {}
        void return_void() {}

        void* operator new (size_t sz) {
            printf("%s %I64d\n", __FUNCTION__, sz);
            return malloc(sz);
        }
    };

    std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> Handle;
};

cCoro stack_or_heap()
{
    const int sz = 64 * 1024 * 1024; // larger than a normal thread stack ... blows stack!!!???
    uint8_t buffer[sz];

    co_await std::suspend_always();

    // ... use buffer here
}

int main()
{
    auto h = stack_or_heap(); // <== stack overflow here ...
}
```

Changing the buffer size as follows works (and operator new gets called):

```
cCoro stack_or_heap()
{
    const int sz = 64 * 1024; // Works
    uint8_t buffer[sz];

    co_await std::suspend_always();

    // ... use buffer here
}
```

I don't understand, are the "local" variables in a C++ coroutine on the stack or not?

I was expecting the allocation to be passed to operator new - irrespective of the size of the buffer. I do not expect to get a stack overflow ...

Looking at godbolt disassembly, the code is adding the buffer size to the stack as it enters the coroutine - and also passing the buffer size and the extra bytes for to coroutine state to operator new

```
cCoro stack_or_heap(void) PROC           ; stack_or_heap
$LN1:
        mov     eax, 67109128                   ; 04000108H
        call    __chkstk
        sub     rsp, rax
        xor     eax, eax
        test    eax, eax
        je      SHORT $LN8@stack_or_h
        lea     rax, QWORD PTR $T2[rsp]
        mov     QWORD PTR tv73[rsp], rax
        jmp     SHORT $LN9@stack_or_h
$LN8@stack_or_h:
        mov     eax, 67109040                   ; 040000b0H
        mov     ecx, eax
        call    static void * cCoro::promise_type::operator new(unsigned __int64)       ; cCoro::promise_type::operator new
        mov     QWORD PTR tv73[rsp], rax
```

I don't understand why the thread's stack is involved with the buffer[sz] at all, when this is allocated as part of the C++ coroutine's state (via operator new)? There is no need for the buffer[sz] to be in the stack frame is there?

Why is space being added to the stack frame AND space being allocated via operator new for the same buffer?

Comment: The compiler allocates the coroutine state on the stack if heap elision is detected. Notice that the stack used is at the `lea rax, QWORD PTR $T2[rsp]`. Heap elision is not active here (hard-coded false at the `xor eax, eax`), but it looks like the peephole optimizer did not realize that the stack allocation is now dead code. You didn't specify what optimization level you compiled at.

Comment: @RaymondChen - I used default godbolt latest MSVC with std=c++20 nothing else.

Comment: @RaymondChen, are you implying that with the correct optimisations set, I could make a 64MB local buffer in a Coroutine?

Comment: Looks like at optimization level `-O1`, the dead code is removed, but the stack reservation remains. It doesn't go away at level `-O2` either. If you want to force the memory onto the heap, then put it on the heap (`std::make_unique_for_overwrite<uint8_t>(size)`). Otherwise, the compiler always has the option of putting it on the stack. For example, if there are no `co_await`s during the buffer's lifetime, it is eligible for placement on the stack, even if the rest of the coroutine state is on the heap.

Comment: @RaymondChen, I was wondering if I could get a large buffer added to the coroutine’s state and force that whole allocate to be one heap allocation?

Comment: The language does not give you that level of control over the coroutine state. All the language says is "An implementation may need to allocate additional storage for a coroutine." What counts as 'needed' is up to the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Local variables are part of the coroutine's state. Whether they are considered "on the stack" by some definition is a matter for the implementation to work out. C++ implementations are permitted to have all kinds of limitations on how much space is available for various operations, including the size of a coroutine state.

It may consider such a circumstance to be a "stack overflow" if it is due to the coroutine's state exceeding some limitation on the size of the stack which a coroutine function is allowed to use. But again, that's all up to the implementation.

---

Perhaps the problem is that you're thinking of "the stack" and "the heap" as disjointed concepts. An object is on one or the other, but not both. While this is a conceptually useful distinction, it's not really true.

Memory is *memory*; at the bottom, there is no "stack memory" or "heap memory".

The term "the heap" usually is used to refer to some pool of memory whose acquisition and release is managed by the application's runtime explicitly. Whereas "the stack" usually refers to memory used by a function's automatic variables, where allocation is managed automatically based on which functions you call in what order.

But this is just a high-level overview. At the bottom, there is just memory.

"The stack" is a region of memory which a particular thread of execution is attached to. That is, when a CPU thread is operating, it has some conceptual region of memory that is its "stack". It *does not care* where this memory comes from.

The takehome point is this: memory is "the stack" because it is being *used as a stack frame*. It is not an inherent property of memory, and it has *nothing to do* with where that memory came from.

The point of a coroutine is that its execution can be paused and resumed. To do this, the content of any local variables must be preserved. But normally, the memory used by a thread's stack is contiguous. To make a coroutine work, the coroutine's local variables must be in storage that is disconnected from any particular thread's stack.

That's where the memory allocation comes in. The coroutine state is a set of data which includes objects used to manage the coroutine, but it *also* includes a chunk of memory which the coroutine uses as its stack. Storage for this memory must be allocated when the coroutine starts. And when the coroutine is done, it must be deallocated.

Remember: "the stack" *does not care* where the memory comes from. Memory is a "stack" based on usage, not how it was allocated. So a piece of memory, allocated from "the heap," can in fact be used as a stack. There is no contradiction here.

Comment: Trying to find the limit you mention, I have found:  
    sz = 1 * 1024 * 1024 - 20 * 1024; 
Gets an interesting error - where operator new gets called, but then the printf blows the stack! Assuming the default C++ thread has a 1MB stack limit, this just about fits.

Comment: I think I understand more now. The "stored state" of the coroutine needs to be put into a persistent allocation (via operator new) - but the state when its running is on the stack - just like normal functions. Is that right?

Comment: Actually this doesn't make sense! Why would there be two copies of the buffer, one on the stack, the other part of the coroutine's state?

Comment: @DrJamesCain: I didn't say anything about "copies" of anything. I'm not sure I understand the point of questioning whether this is "on the stack" or not. The point of the error is that you have exceeded the limits of your C++ implementation. Whether that limit is called a "stack" or "coroutine state" or whatever is kind of irrelevant.

Comment: @DrJamesCain: This is not a forum. If there is some additional information needed to answer a question, you put it *in the question*. It's also unclear how this information is useful. It seems to me that you're thinking of "stack" and "heap" as disjointed concepts. That is, something is either "on the stack" or "on the heap", but never both.

Comment: @DrJamesCain: Assuming this is about a misunderstanding of the terms "stack" and "heap", I've added additional clarifying info.

Comment: Thanks again @Nicol Bolas. Please see the disassembly I have (now) added to the question. Why is space being added to the stack frame AND space being allocated via operator new for the same buffer?

Comment: @DrJamesCain: I thought my post made that clear: the "heap" (or operator `new`) is about how you manage access to memory, and the "stack" is about how memory gets used by the CPU. These are two distinct operations. What is your confusion?

Comment: I’m not confused about my understanding of stack and heap. I’m surprised by the buffer in my example having memory allocated for it twice - on the stack AND on the heap. See the disassembly I added to the question.

Comment: @DrJamesCain For me this is no surprise. From what I understood how coroutines are implemented, indeed local variables are placed on stack, so that regular indexing can be used in the function, **and** variables that needs to be persisted across `co_await` must be copied to the coroutine state block at coroutine suspending. So yes, basically all local variables are allocated twice.

Comment: @DrJamesCain: "*See the disassembly I added to the question.*" I've seen it. Moving the stack pointer is not "allocation" in the same way that calling `operator new` is. One is getting memory and declaring that it is now being used. The other is adjusting how a CPU thread is going to access its available stack memory. If you believe these two operations are different forms of the same kind of "allocation" operation, then you are indeed "confused about [your] understanding of stack and heap".

Comment: OK - I am confused then! :-) How is moving the stack pointer not allocation? With a normal function call, local variables are allocated on the stack by moving the stack pointer. alloca() works like this too …

Comment: @prapin: That implementation would be *completely broken*. You can get pointers to stack variables. If the stack was a separate allocation from the coroutine state, then those pointers would not be pointed to the state that gets preserved. But there's nothing in the C++ standard that prevents you from getting pointers to coroutine automatic variables, and it says that these objects will exist beyond the coroutine's suspension. So it would violate the standard to implement these via copying.

Comment: @DrJamesCain: "*How is moving the stack pointer not allocation?*" I said "is not 'allocation' **in the same way**" as `operator new`. They are not *comparable* operations. They are not *equivalent* operations.

Comment: In other words - why increase the stack pointer by 64MB in this example? What’s it for?

Comment: @DrJamesCain: Because that's *what you told it to do* when you made a 64MB automatic variable. It would do the same thing in any other function. Coroutines are only special in *where their stack lives*, not in how they operate on it.

Comment: @prapin - that certainly seems like what the assembly code is doing - which is rather shocking!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251478/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-dr-james-cain).

Comment: @NicolBolas, could you possibly please supply some reading or links so I can study how C++ Coroutines persist their local state across invocations? As I’m not getting what’s going on and I fear I’m waisting if you time! Thanks.

Comment: @DrJamesCain: Please join the chat if you want to continue discussion of this matter. Comments aren't for this kind of thing.